# How to scrape data from a dynamic website with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium and want to **scrape price** and **offer end time** from a Udemy Course link.  How can i do this?

The price and course end time is dynamically loaded to the website. I know how to extract simple content from the website but not dynamic content.

I have tried with **Parsel Library** + **Seleminium Library** but returns empty string. Because when i view-source the website in my mobile there is not price shown in source. But when i click on inspect element option of chrome or firefox. The price is provided inside a span tag. Means that when the page is rendered on browser the price is dynamically loaded. How can i do this in Selenium?

Here is an example Udemy Course link:

https://www.udemy.com/course/data-science-deep-learning-in-python/

Comment: Hi!  Please show us what you have tried, provide data and sample code, and what research you have tried.  Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how we could best help you.

Comment: I have provided all the information. Please answer this question now..

Comment: can you share your code segment here ?

Comment: Why not use `udemy-dl` - https://github.com/r0oth3x49/udemy-dl?

Comment: Because i want to make my own...I can't share my code segment here.. sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all dependencies already installed in your environment, this code should work:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get("https://www.udemy.com/course/appium-selenium-for-mobile-automation-testing/")

    content = driver.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

    price = soup.find('div', {'class':'price-text--price-part--Tu6MH udlite-clp-discount-price udlite-heading-xl'})
    if price is not None:
        price.text.strip()
        price = price.replace('Current price','')
        print('Price: ' + price)
        
        offerEndTime = soup.find('span', {'data-purpose':'safely-set-inner-html:discount-expiration:expiration-text'}).text.strip()
        print('Offer end time: ' +  offerEndTime)
    else:
        print('This is a free course')
```

Comment: Bro this works fine for this link... But when I test it with another url it will show error... Any Solution for this....

Comment: Which url have you tried? I tested with other urls and it still working

Comment: URL is https://www.udemy.com/course/appium-selenium-for-mobile-automation-testing/ and the error is ```2020-08-08T15:43:39.189996+00:00 app[worker.1]:     price = soup2.find('div', {'class':'price-text--price-part--Tu6MH udlite-clp-discount-price udlite-heading-xl'}).text.strip()
2020-08-08T15:43:39.189996+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' ``` I am running on Heroku

Comment: This is Free Course that's why i am getting error sorry bro... Now my problem is done...

Comment: How can I print get **FREE** if Course is Free Forever Like this

Comment: I editted the answer with the two conditions, just an advice: you should always include "https://www." at the beginning of the URL

Comment: Hello Bro Thanks for Your Help... I am also having trouble in extracting a link from this website https://couponscorpion.com/development/deploying-android-apps-to-different-app-stores-correctly/ I want to Scrap Free Course Link From here but this is returning me empty list I am tried with the following code

Comment: ```driver.get(https://couponscorpion.com/development/deploying-android-apps-to-different-app-stores-correctly/ )
    udemy_links = []
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    course_link = soup.find_all('div',{'class':"rh_button_wrapper"})


    for i in course_link:
        link = i.find('a',href=True)
        if link is None:
           print('No Links Found')
        print(link['href'])```

Comment: Hello V K, you're welcome :) I saw your last question and it appears to be answered, so I think your problem is already solved, right?

Comment: Yes my Problem is Solved :)